# jQuery check iFrame height and adjust

Tags: jquery, iframe, height

I'm trying to change the size of an iFrame based on the size of the content within the iFrame, the challenge comes from when the user starts clicking around within the iFrame, to check the state of the iFrame I use an interval to check the content size like so

```
var checkHeight = setInterval(function(){
checkHeight();
},1000);

function checkHeight() {
  var height = $('.foo').contents().height();
  console.log(height)
  $('.foo').css({
  'height': height + 'px'
  });
}
```

Which is fine, when a user goes to a page where the content is 600px, the iFrame is set to 600px, but when a user then goes to a page where the height is 200px, the iFrame logs out and sets 600px, I can't work out why jQuery is saving the highest height number? setting the value to zero on each function call makes the page bounch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#foo').load(function(){ 
        $('#foo').contents().find("body").on('click', function(event) { 
            runAfterTimeout('foo');
        });
    });
});

function runAfterTimeout(id) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        autoResize(id);
    },1000);
};

function autoResize(id){
    var newheight;
    var newwidth;

    if(document.getElementById){
        newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
        newwidth=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
    }

    document.getElementById(id).height=(newheight) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width=(newwidth) + "px"; 
}
```

And on the iframe add this: onload="autoResize('foo')"